# Javascript: Sort arrays based on each array's length number

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I sort these arrays (from array with most amount of items inside to least)? I think the logic is there but there are methods I am missing. Output shows nothing.

```
//Declare Variables
var TN = ['Chattanooga', 'Nashville', 'Memphis'],
    FL = ['Tampa', 'Miami', 'Orlando', 'Clearwater'],
    GA = ['Atlanta', 'Marietta'];



//write function to sort array from most to least
function sortStates(a, b){
    return a - b;
}


//Make an object to get total in each array. 
var stateTotal = {
        totalTN: TN.length,
        totalFL: FL.length,
        totalGA: GA.length
};

//Sort states in order
stateTotal.sort(sortStates);

console.log(stateTotal);
```

Desired Output: `totalFL: 4, totalTN: 3, totalGA: 2`

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: You are doing sort directly on object.  i think sort takes an array like array.sort()

Comment: @Stratubas sorry- I've included it at the bottom. I want it to sort the arrays in most to least amount of values in each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stuff inside objects can't be "sorted". Stuff in arrays can be sorted.

Is this some kind of exercise? `Make an object to get total in each array.` is vague.

Anyway, take a look at this snippet.

```js
//Declare Variables
var TN = ['Chattanooga', 'Nashville', 'Memphis'],
    FL = ['Tampa', 'Miami', 'Orlando', 'Clearwater'],
    GA = ['Atlanta', 'Marietta'];

//write function to sort array from most to least
function sortStates(a, b) {
    return b.total - a.total;
}

//Make an object to get total in each array. 
var stateTotal = [
    { name: 'totalTN', total: TN.length },
    { name: 'totalFL', total: FL.length },
    { name: 'totalGA', total: GA.length }
];

//Sort states in order
stateTotal.sort(sortStates);

stateTotal.forEach(info => {
  console.log(`${info.name}: ${info.total}`);
});
```

Comment: perfect! I was missing the `foreach` part. Didn't even think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do the sort on length of states is

```
var states=[];
states.push({
    name:"TN",
    towns:['Chattanooga', 'Nashville', 'Memphis']
    });
states.push({
    name:"FL",
    towns:['Tampa', 'Miami', 'Orlando', 'Clearwater']
    });
states.push({
    name:"GA",
    towns:['Atlanta', 'Marietta']
});
states.sort((state1,state2) => state2.towns.length - state1.towns.length).forEach( state => console.log(`total${state.name}:${state.towns.length}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with objects and arrays can be confusing.  Arrays->[] may be sorted.  Object properties are not sorted.

```js
//Declare Variables
var myData = {TN:['Chattanooga', 'Nashville', 'Memphis'],
              FL:['Tampa', 'Miami', 'Orlando', 'Clearwater'],
              GA:['Atlanta', 'Marietta']};

var keys=Object.keys(myData);

var mySort=[];
for(key in keys){
   mySort.push([keys[key],myData[keys[key]].length]);
}

mySort.sort(function(a, b){
    return b[1] - a[1];
});

myObj={};

for(let i=0;i<mySort.length;i++){

myObj["total" + mySort[i][0]] = mySort[i][1]

}

console.log(myObj);
```